# How to call ModelAndView method or getting reference to it in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I reflect how is possible to call method or get property value using getter in ModelAndView through JSP page using extended class.

For example:

I would extends class ModelAndView to class View and implements there some methods to getting some data.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class View extends ModelAndView {

    private Map store = new HashMap<>() ;

    public Object getElement(String index) {
        return store.get(index);
    }

    public void setElement(String index,Object o) {
         store.put(index,o);
    }

}
```

Now controller which will handle approaching request.

```
public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController {

    private String viewName;

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        View v = new View("example.jsp");
        v.setElement("test", "Hello im test!");
        return v

        // I would not use here method addObject();
        // how put reference to jsp page of View (ModelAndView)
        // code like this return StackOverflowError
        // v.addObject("reference_to_view",v);
    }

}
```

Nothing remains, except getting my string test from View in JSP page:

example.jsp

```
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    // how can i here call method getElement of object View.
    ${this.getElement("test")}
    ${getElement("test")}
</body>
```

How can i call method getElement(); of object View which was returned from WelcomeController

Comment: I think in JSP you can't access the whole ModelAndView just the items of its ModelMap, so you have to add your store to it with addObject(..)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to call methods from within a JSP. And that's the reason of the `ModelAndView` from Spring : you give a reference to a view, and fills a model with attributes that will be easily accessible from the view.

```
public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController {

    private String viewName;

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("example.jsp");
        mav.addObject("test", "Hello im test");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can simply access to any object from the sub-jacent model :

```
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    ${test}
</body>
```

If you **really** want to use your element construct to mimic Spring `ModelMap`, the simplest way would be to expose your own map to Spring model with `v.addObject("element", store);`. Then in your JSP, you could do :

```
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    // how can i here call method getElement of object View.
    ${element["test"]}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe i am wrong, but can't you define your controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = WelcomeController.CONTROLLER_NAME)
public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController {

public static final String CONTROLLER_NAME = "welcomeController";
..
public String calculateSomeValue() {
   return "Hello";
}
}
```

and use it in the jsf page so:

```
<body>
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    ${welcomeController.calculateSomeValue()}
</body>
```